# Progress bar on button click

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Using the help of the following youtube video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ePuCsvwoHMo I would like to get a progress bar moving (progressing) on button click with ZERO Delphi experiences.

I am trying based on google search and stackoverflow past, similar, questions but with no luck. What should this single line of code (or maximum two) look like and where do I type it?

The second question that is unrelated to first one is:

Is there any website (web application) where I can use Delphi online - actually on the website?

Comment: In regards to your second question, no. Delphi is a compiled language, and actually creates executable files in order to run (even for debugging), so it's not available interactively on a web site. You can get the [Lazarus](http://http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org) IDE that uses [FreePascal](http://http://www.freepascal.org), if you need a free version to experiment with, but it doesn't have the same capabilities as Delphi. The syntax is the same for most things, though.

Comment: One can try the Pascal language, however, in simple 'console-like' mode at IDEOne: http://ideone.com/RksOC.

Comment: If you get a Windows web server, you can run your application there. Alternatively, with FireMonkey, you could also use a Mac web host.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a new VCL project. Drop a `TButton` and a `TProgressBar` on the main form. Now, double-click the button, and write

```
ProgressBar1.StepBy(1)
```

Now you can move the progress bar by repeatedly clicking the button.

If you want the progressbar to move by itself, then you need a `TTimer`, so drop one such onto the main form. Set its `Enabled` property to `false`, using the Object Inspector. Also, set `Interval` to `60`. Now, double-click the timer, and write

```
ProgressBar1.Position := (ProgressBar1.Position + 1) mod ProgressBar1.Max;
```

Go back to your form, and double-click the button. Remove the code you wrote earlier, and write, instead,

```
Timer1.Enabled := not Timer1.Enabled;
```

Now run your project. You can toggle the animation (run, stop) using the button.

Comment: Thank you a lot Andreas. Helped.

Comment: @YesPlease, if this answer solved your problem you should accept it as correct. (Click the checkmark at the top left of this answer, just below the vote count.) Accepting answers lets others know your problem has been solved, and acknowledges the work that the person answering has done to help you. (It also gains you a little reputation at the same time.) See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/172661) for more information. :-)